# Listing a professor as a reference who hasn't responded to my request

Tags: reference-request

This is the age-old reference-letter-no-response problem, but with a small twist. I'm applying to a programme where the applications close very soon. I have been trying to reach a professor over the last two weeks who supervised me for a research project but despite several attempts to contact him on both his old and current institutional addresses (he's moved institutions recently), I've not heard back from him. I asked one of his grad students today if he was out of office and they said he had been quite busy managing a thesis defence for another one of his students (fair enough).

He's been happy to give his consent to act as a reference for internships and the like in the past and the form only requires that I list the names and details of potential referees. Should I list him as a reference with a note that I've been trying to reach him to get his consent and have been unable to and will tell the admissions committee as soon as I am able to if he cannot act as a reference?

The other option would be to not list him as a reference, but I feel as though that would significantly weaken my application as this research project is very much related to the doctoral project I will be applying for.

Comment: Any chance you can go visit in person?

Comment: "He's been happy to give his consent to act as a reference for internships and the like in the past" - how long ago was that?  Also, have you tried other contact methods than email (e.g. phone)?